# SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found sqlplus oracle

Tags: oracle, linux, sqlplus

I've a linux RedHat which contains oracle database. I setted all environnement variables, but when I running `sqlplus` command I've this error : `SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found`

Here are my variables ans my `sqlplus` commands :

```
[oracle@as ~]$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
[oracle@as ~]$ echo $ORA_NLS33
/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/nls/data
[oracle@as ~]$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/lib
[oracle@as ~]$ sqlplus
Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

Note that I'm currently running as `oracle` user, which seems to be the owner of the `/oracle` folder with read and excecute permission. I also seen that a file named sp1us.msb exists in the following folder :

```
[oracle@as ~]$ find $ORACLE_HOME | grep sp1
/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/sqlplus/mesg/sp1us.msb
/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/sqlplus/mesg/sp1us.msg
```

Comment: This might be useful:http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/faq101-094300.html#A4828

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution ! As the oracle documentation said about ORACLE_HOME, My env variables was setted in the /etc/profilefile, but not visible from env | grep ORACLE_HOME or dbhomeso I executed the following command :

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
```

and now it works